# Efficiently dividing a double by a power of 2

Tags: c++, c, x86

I'm implementing a coherent noise function, and was surprised to find that using gradient noise (i.e. Perlin noise) is actually slightly faster than value noise. Profiling shows that the reason for this is the division needed to convert the random int value into a double of range -1.0 to 1.0:

```
static double noiseValueDouble(int seed, int x, int y, int z) {
    return 1.0 - ((double)noiseValueInt(seed, x, y, z) / 1073741824.0);
}
```

Gradient noise requires a few multiplies more, but due to the precomputed gradient table uses the `noiseValueInt` directly to compute an index into the table, and doesn't require any division. So my question is, how could I make the above division more efficient, considering that the division is by a power of 2 (2^30).

Theoretically all that would need to be done is to subtract 30 from the double's exponent, but doing that by brute force (i.e. bit manipulation) would lead to all sorts of corner cases (INF, NAN, exponent overflow, etc.). An x86 assembly solution would be ok.

Comment: Are you sure it matters that much? Using machine specific bit manipulation is non-portable, and might even hit performance because of caching or scheduling issues...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's what I meant with my last paragraph. I don't want to do bit manipulation assuming IEEE 754, but would be fine with an x86-specific assembly solution.

Comment: I won't bother about that. You won't win much, and you could lose some performance.

Comment: If you have optimizations turned on, the compiler should already be replacing the divide with a multiply by the reciprocal.

Comment: Please post the alternative function.

Comment: @spraff There is no alternative function, gradient noise uses the result of `noiseValueInt` directly to choose the gradient from a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare a variable (or constant) with the inverse value and multiply by it, effectively changing the division to a multiplication:

```
static const double div_2_pow_30 = 1.0 / 1073741824.0;
```

Another way (utilizing the property that the number is a power of 2) is to modify the exponent with bit operations. Doing that will make the code dependant on doubles being stored using the IEEE standard which may be less portable.

Comment: I was going to say the compiler can figure that out, but actually no, [it could lead to different numerical results](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/will-it-optimize.html) (unless you use e.g. -ffast-math for gcc).

Comment: @spraff: In the case that the divisor is an exact power of two, and its reciprocal does not overflow or underflow, the result is always the same.  Most compilers are aware of this, and do this optimization.

Comment: You mean `const double f = 1.0 / 1073741824.0;`, of course. As in, if it's a constant, make it `const`!

Comment: I now feel silly for not trying this, but yes, this was it. GCC 4.4.3 with -O2 apparently doesn't optimize this automatically.

Comment: Surely when you say "modify the *mantissa* with bit operations", you mean the *exponent*, right?

Comment: aix: Yes, I do, thanks for pointing it out. (Updated the answer)

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the exponent directly use the functions `frexp` and `ldexp`. I'm not sure if this would be faster though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can trust the profiling in here. For smaller, faster functions, the effect of the profiling code itself starts to skew the results.

Run `noiseValueDouble` and the corresponding alternative in a loop to get better numbers.

An x86 assembler solution *is* a bit-fiddling solution, you may as well do the bit fiddling in C. Fast power-of-two division instructions (bit shifts) only exist for integers.

If you really want to use special instructions, MMX it up or something.

Comment: Yes, I did this too. The effect, while less, is still there. For gradient noise, the call is `grad(noiseValueInt(seed, x0, y0), x, y)`, for value noise, `noiseValueDouble(seed, x0, y0)`. Other than that, the two algorithms are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I tried compiling this with gcc:

```
double divide(int i) {
    return 1.0 - (double)i / 1073741824.0;
}
```

with `-O3` it is coded as an `FMULS`-instruction, with `-O3 -mfpmath=sse -march=core2` it uses SSE-instruction set and encodes it as `MULSD`.  I have no idea what is the fastest, but the function call itself is probably orders of magnitude slower than the actual division.